# Using Selenium (C#) Select an item from a drop down by text

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have been trying to figure this out and could use some help from Selenium experts here. I have a dropdown on my page that I am trying to select an option for from the test and I cant seem to get this right.
I have tried the following example I see commonly for select Item. The options always show text as an empty *string* "" even though I can see in the HTML markup the option text is there.

```
wait.Until(d => ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("Cars")));
var carStatusDropDown = new SelectElement(_driver.FindElement(By.Id("Cars")));
carStatusDropDown.SelectByText(filter.CarStatus);
```

I figured its because maybe the options are not visible to the browser, so then I tried to click on the button next to dropdown (Bootstrap) so it would be open before it selects the text

```
wait.Until(ElementIsClickable(By.XPath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/fieldset/div[3]/div/div[1]/span[2]/div/div/span")));
IWebElement ddlButton = _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/fieldset/div[3]/div/div[1]/span[2]/div/div/span"));
ddlButton.Click();

wait.Until(d => ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("Cars")));
var carStatusDropDown = new SelectElement(_driver.FindElement(By.Id("Cars")));
carStatusDropDown.SelectByText(filter.CarStatus);
```

I can see the ddlButton opens the dropdown but am still getting >OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException
when it tries to `SelectByText`. In `VS` I can see the the options text still shows "" and the **Displayed** property is false for them. How can I find the options, Any feedback would be appreciated, I am posting the HTML below whats weird is that there are two drop downs one as a `<ul>` and a `<select>` one the appears below, I am trying to access the `<select>` one in the test code. The select one in firebug shows up as faded in the markup?!?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="combobox-container">
   <input type="hidden" name="Estimate.EstimateStatus" value=" ">
   <input type="text" autocomplete="off"  
      placeholder="All"class="combobox">
   <ul class="typeahead typeahead-long dropdown-menu" style="top:   
      112px;left: 445.117px; display: none;">
      <li data-value="Approved" class=""><a href="#"><strong>
         </strong>A<strong></strong>p<strong></strong>p<strong>
         </strong>r<strong></strong>o<strong></strong>v<strong>
         </strong>e<strong></strong>d<strong></strong></a>
      </li>
      <li data-value="Hold" class=""><a href="#"><strong>
         </strong>H<strong>
         </strong>o<strong></strong>l<strong></strong>d<strong></strong>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li data-value="In Progress"><a href="#"><strong></strong>I<strong>
         </strong>n<strong></strong> <strong></strong>P<strong>
         </strong>r<strong></strong>o<strong></strong>g<strong>
         </strong>r<strong></strong>e<strong></strong>s<strong>
         </strong>s<strong></strong></a>
      </li>
      <li data-value="Not Reviewed" class="active">
         <a href="#"><strong></strong>N<strong>
         </strong>o<strong></strong>t<strong></strong> <strong>
         </strong>R<strong></strong>e<strong></strong>v<strong>
         </strong>i<strong></strong>e<strong></strong>w<strong>
         </strong>e<strong></strong>d<strong></strong></a>
      </li>
      <li data-value="Rejected"><a href="#"><strong></strong>R<strong>
         </strong>e<strong></strong>j<strong></strong>e<strong>
         </strong>c<strong></strong>t<strong></strong>e<strong> 
         </strong>d<strong></strong></a>
      </li>
   </ul>
   <span class="add-on btn dropdown-toggle" data-dropdown="dropdown">
   <span class="caret"></span>
   <span class="combobox-clear">
   </span>
</div>
<select id="Cars" class="combobox" 
   onchange="javascript:OnCarsStatusChanged();" style="display: none;">
   <option value=" " selected="selected">All</option>
   <option value="3ad8cf29-f0b7-441f-
      81bc-c5cfe7c0d73d">Approved</option>
   <option value="19b573c8-fc88-4abe-9c19-9ffc580a1ffe">Hold</option>
   <option value="e3a8b2bd-c3eb-47c3-95e7-f15da2f3d25b">In      
      Progress
   </option>
   <option value="962e4bce-1ca5-404f-b7a0-6a3a42ad91a0">Not 
      Reviewed
   </option>
   <option value="c110e83a-5a93-4553-
      a907-02a47ca97467">Rejected</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you please share the `html` as well?

Comment: just updated with the html as well

Comment: I'm far from an expert in how Bootstrap works, but what it looks like is that the actual `<select>` element is invisible, and the JavaScript widget framework uses `<div>`, `<input>`, and `<ul>` elements to simulate a dropdown list, and the JavaScript behind the scenes actually sets the value of the `<select>` element. You can either make the `<select>` visible via JavaScript (bypassing the Bootstrap framework), or manipulate the actual, visible elements on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does seems like there is another action depended on this dropdwon. By default this dropdown is **NOT** visible. So, best will be to see what previous action makes it visible.

However, another workaround can be to execute a simple javascript, make the dropdown list visible and select the intended element you need.
`removeAttribute` should remove the `style` attribute to make the list visible.

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver).ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('Cars').removeAttribute('style');");

By id = By.Id('Cars');
var carStatusDropDown = new SelectElement(_driver.FindElement(id));
carStatusDropDown.SelectByText(filter.CarStatus);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Saifur....I was stuck on that for a bit, I used the Javascript to remove the style element and then the SelectElement was able to select by text...hope it helps someone else too